# Windows task scheduler can run batch file but not fire command inside for winzip

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have task schedule for backup directory list of wwwroot. For that I have written batch file.

```
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%i in ('time /t') do set Hma=%%i%%j%%k
set yyyymmdd=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%Hma%

set FolderPath=D:\SystemBackup\DirListFiles\

dir c:\inetpub\wwwroot /s /o-d > %FolderPath%\DirList_%yyyymmdd%.txt
```

batch file will do correct at this point but after this

```
echo "Upload To FTP Start"

cd /d c:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\

winzip32.exe /autorunjobfile d:\BackupScript\DirList.wjf

echo "Upload FTP Complete !"

cd /d %FolderPath%

del DirList_%yyyymmdd%.txt
```

Not working well. It does not winzip well and also not send to ftp server.

Comment: it would help us if you tell us what error you get, how you get the failure and what steps you have done to debug the problem.

Comment: The first part is working well as it is created txt file but after that to send over ftp server not done. usually when I made direct run to batch file it take 2 minutes for finish all and it is done well  but the winzip command not work in task schedule and its take so many hors so I have to stop it. and task schedule showing (0 * 41306) error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From forum of Winzip, I found that if you want to run winzip job in batch mode than first time should run manually and winzip open one dialog box. Tick to do not ask again checkbox. so that task scheduler do not wait for prompt.

Answer (score 0):

for the first part, winzip not working, you need to review your winzip job file and post here the failing part.

**EDIT** Ooops I was wrong.... you don't need to enclose the path in quotes. Sorry.

<strike>CD needs you to enclose the path in quotes, instead of</strike>

```
cd /d c:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\
```

try

```
pushd "c:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\"
```

for the second part, ftp not working, again you need to review your winzip job file and post here the failing part.